# How to make a QLabel turn to be a combobox or edit control, when you clicked this label

Tags: qt

It looks like a label normally, once you move the mouse over it, or clicked it, then will turn to be a edit control or combobox likewise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a QStackedWidget. According to the docs, "The QStackedWidget class provides a stack of widgets where only one widget is visible at a time." You can then reimplement QWidget::enterEvent and QWidget::leaveEvent to detect mouse overs and show the appropriate widget.